# How is C sizeof() returning these values

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, sizeof

I've got the code below in trying to understand memory allocation under C. The comments next to the line indicate the output I got. Apart from the char size that comes up I'm confused, though. Is this output standard? If so, how is it coming to these returns?

---

```
char *pk[] = {"12", "34", "56"};
int w[2][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};
int (*ppw)[2][3] = &w;

char ch = "a";
int in = 10;

int i = sizeof(ch);
printf("SIZE OF CHAR IS %d\n",i); //1

i = sizeof(in);
printf("SIZE OF INT IS %d\n\n",i); //4

int n = sizeof(pk);
printf("%d\n",n); //24

n = sizeof(*pk);
printf("%d\n",n); //8

n = sizeof(**pk);
printf("%d\n",n); //1

n = sizeof(ppw);
printf("%d\n",n); //8

n = sizeof(*ppw);
printf("%d\n",n); //24

n = sizeof(**ppw); 
printf("%d\n",n); //12
```

---

Comment: go read the wikipedia first

Comment: and `char ch = "a";` is not doing what you want it to do

Comment: All these sizes seem correct to me, you should fix this line: `char ch = "a";` should read `char ch = 'a';`

Comment: Are you familiar with binary representation of data (bytes, words, etc).

Comment: No, this output is not standard. But is very well conforms to it. apart from  `char ch = "a"` which should generate an error message or at least a warning actually). Let me guess: that is an 64 bit OS with 32 bit integers? Btw. `sizeof(char)` always returns 1. **This** is actually defined by the standard. Did you have a specific question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your system has 8-byte pointers and 4-byte ints. Remember that `*p` means `p[0]`

`sizeof(pk)` is sizeof an array of 3 pointers = `24`

`sizeof(*pk)` is sizeof the first pointer in the array = `8`

`sizeof(**pk)` is sizeof(char) which is `1`

`sizeof(ppw)` is sizeof a pointer = `8`

`sizeof(*ppw)` is sizeof an array(3x2) of ints = 6 ints = `24`

`sizeof(**ppw)` is sizeof an array(3) of ints = 3 ints = `12`

Comment: This is perfect thank you. Had been thrown off by 8-byte pointers (hadn't realised the difference between 32 and 64 bit) and the 'array of three pointers' rather than 'array of three chars'.